# PHP: Undefined variable

Tags: php, class, variables, scope

I have the code below. For some reason when I run this code it say the variable rsLinks is undefined. Yet clearly you can see that it is defined in the constructor. Can you tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
 require_once "..\Models\Links.php";

class Navigator
{
    public $rsLinks;

    public function __construct() 
    { 
        $rsLinks = new rsLinks();
    }

    public function getLinks()
    {
        $links = $rsLinks;
    }
}

$navigator = new Navigator();
$navigator->getLinks();
```

Comment: I expect this has something to do with scoping.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `$this->rsLinks;` instead.

Comment: Oh thank you. Now I feel dumb. Thanks Odinn so quickly as well!

Comment: I personally hate the fact that you have to use $this in PHP... :) you welcome.

Answer (score 1):

```
public function getLinks()
{
    //$links = $rsLinks;
    $links = $this->rsLinks;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`$rsLinks` is a regular local variable with function scope.
To access *object properties*, use `$this->rsLinks`.

Answer (score 0):

Php is not Java. You need to use $this.

```
$this->rsLink
```

On both cases.

Comment: You speak the truth. I keep forgetting that.