# PHP forms submitting duplicate entries to MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I have a database that has data written to it by 3 different forms. The good news is that the forms do write to the database. The bad news is that every time I hit the submit button on one of the forms, a duplicate entry gets created along with the first one.

The forms are online at http://digitaldemo.net/kickass/test.php It is not hooked up to a live database, but I wanted to get it online so that you can see the code.

Here is the add_player.php code that writes the form data to the database:

```
<?php

// contact to database
$connect = mysql_connect("localhost", "dariia", "celtic03") or die ("Error , check your server connection.");
mysql_select_db("football");

// Set up form variables //

//Get data in local variable
$Player=$_POST['Player'];
$Position=$_POST['Position'];
$Team=$_POST['Team'];

// check for null values
$query="INSERT INTO ff_projections(Player, Position, Team) VALUES('$Player','$Position','$Team')";
mysql_query($query)  or die(mysql_error());
echo "1 record has been entered.";

mysql_query($query) or die('Error, query failed');

?>
```

Comment: I think it is duplicating because you gave all your form elements the same name, so there is nothing wrong with PHP behavior, I think you need to rethink your forms structure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You execute the query twice!!

```
mysql_query($query)  or die(mysql_error());

mysql_query($query) or die('Error, query failed');
```

Comment: LOL oh my god. I have been coding WAY too many hours today. I feel
like such a doofus.

Comment: That is so funny. I did something similar yesterday. Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10630743/php-undefined-variable I really thought I was going crazy!! @user1255168

Comment: Funny how it happens like that sometimes. This is really my first foray into programming database functionality from the ground up. It's nerve wracking, but exhilarating too when things work.